# How to remove the second rotation in ng2chart js libary with angular4

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, chartjs-2.6.0

I have used for ng2chart library for doughnut chart,and pass the dynamic value in the donut chart,when passing the chart its going into full rotation.

when it comes as 50 means donut rotation as half rotation , when it reaches 75 means it will be 3/4 rotation,according to the dynamic value,the donut is rotating, need to remove the second rotation, how to do that?

here is a library used for doughnut:

```
https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#doughnutChart
```

while filling the donut chart center hole as white, we can able to observe the second rotation very clearly?

Problem: need to remove the second rotation else need to remove the second rotation end border.

here is a demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/V5n26VA1LkdYE4wLer6H?p=preview.

Any one face this issue or better suggestion be appreciated

Comment: Your plunkr let me sintax error on console.

Comment: @Daniel Segura Pérez its working fine for me,which error got in console,can you share the error.